# jQuery - custom event-bindings

Tags: jquery, events

In my application if have some kind of scoring-part, where the user can increase/decrease scores of a player by clicking the +/- button.

Because a players score consists of mulitple parts, a summarized score is calculated on each `click` of the +/- button.

The summarized score is a simple `span`-Element containing the score.

Is there any way I can bind to a custom event like:

```
$("#mySpanElement").on("namespace.scorechange", function(evt, someAdditionalData){
    // update content by fetching values from event and summarize score

    // set new value
    $(this).text(myCalculatedScore);
});
```

and fire it on each click-of a button?

```
$("#increaseButton1").on("click", function(){
    // do some stuff -> e.g. updating ui

    // fire event that score has been changed and span can update its content
    $.event.trigger("namespace.scorechange"); // not working
    $(document).trigger("namespace.scorechange"); // not working
});
```

So, I am looking for a way to bind to custom events which can be fired someweher in the application.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger the event for the span element.

```js
$("#mySpanElement").on("scorechange.namespace", function(evt, someAdditionalData) {
  snippet.log('event fired: ' + evt.type)
});


$("#increaseButton1").on("click", function() {
  $("#mySpanElement").trigger('scorechange.namespace');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<span id="mySpanElement"></span>
<button id="increaseButton1">Test</button>
```

---

If you don't know for which event it has to be fired, then it is better to bind handler to document object as below and inside the handler you can target any element you want.

```js
$(document).on("scorechange.namespace", function(evt, someAdditionalData) {

  $("#mySpanElement").text(someAdditionalData);

  snippet.log('event fired: ' + evt.type)
});

var counter = 0;
$("#increaseButton1").on("click", function() {
  $(document).trigger('scorechange.namespace', 'Click: ' + ++counter);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<span id="mySpanElement"></span>
<button id="increaseButton1">Test</button>
```

Comment: But in the `click`-event for the button I don't know about the `span`. It's like I'm trying to trigger an anonymous event and whatever element can bind to it

Comment: This will do the trick. I guess there is no easy c#-like way where any element can bind to an custom `event` without going via `document`?